# Auto populate a date series based on given start and end dates

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I am creating a burndown chart in Google Sheets based on ticket information from JIRA. I have the `begindate` and `enddate` of a project in cells. What I want is to have a chart with every date during the running of the project and the burndown data.

I can (and have done) this manually, but a chart where I just need to paste the ticket information, fill in the JIRA dates and everything else works out, without doing any more manual stuff.

The big problem I'm having at the moment is creating a sheet where it will fill out all the dates between the beginning and end date, so it will look something like this:

beginning: `6/1/2015` and end: `6/15/2015`

auto-populate tab to create chart with dates:

```
6/1/2015
6/2/2015
6/3/2015
...
6/15/2015
```

"Dragging down" is not suitable because the chart is too complicated and needs to work with too many people. So need more automation than that.

Is this possible, and how so?

Comment: Is this online? Like the end date change everyday to current until the end of the project?

Comment: What we do right now:

We edit the tickets multiple times a week (this is one tab in the sheet)
We edit the end dates a few times a month (this is another tab in the sheet, containing start and end date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `6/1/2015` in F1 and `6/15/2015` in G1 please try:

```
=array_constrain(arrayformula(row(A1:A100)+F$1-1),G$1-F$1+1,1)
```

Comment: Works! Awesome! Thnx!